# FuncAnimation doesn't show outside of function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I gave an answer on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48152754/matplotlib-plot-points-over-time-where-old-points-fade/48153039#48153039), talking about fading point on matplotlib. And I got curious about ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer. So I tried to play around with his code.

First, here is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

def get_new_vals():
    x = 0
    y = 0
    while True:
        if x >= .9:
            x = 0
            y = 0
        x += .1
        y += .1
        yield x, y

def update(t, x_vals, y_vals, intensity, scatter, gen):
    #   Get intermediate points
    new_xvals, new_yvals = gen.next()
    x_vals.extend([new_xvals])
    y_vals.extend([new_yvals])

    #   Put new values in your plot
    scatter.set_offsets(np.c_[x_vals, y_vals])

    #   Calculate new color values
    for index in range(len(intensity)):
        if intensity[index] < .1:
            intensity[index] = 0
        intensity[index] *= .6
    intensity.extend(1 for _ in xrange(len([new_xvals])))

    intens_dup = np.array(intensity)

    """
    intensity = np.concatenate((np.array(intensity) * .6, np.ones(len(new_xvals))))
    """
    scatter.set_array(intens_dup)

    # Set title
    axis.set_title('Time: %0.3f' % t)

def anim_random_points(fig, axis):
    x_vals = []
    y_vals = []
    intensity = []
    iterations = 100

    colors = [ [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0.5], [0, 0.2, 0.4, 1] ]
    cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", colors)
    scatter = axis.scatter(x_vals, y_vals, c=[], cmap=cmap, vmin=0, vmax=1)

    gen_values = get_new_vals()

    ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=iterations,
        interval=50, fargs=(x_vals, y_vals, intensity, scatter, gen_values),
        repeat=False)

    #   Position 1 for plt.show()
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    fig, axis = plt.subplots()
    axis.set_xlabel('X Axis', size = 12)
    axis.set_ylabel('Y Axis', size = 12)
    axis.axis([0,1,0,1])

    anim_random_points(fig, axis)

    #   Position 2 for plt.show()
    # plt.show()
```

I, then, noticed an odd thing. At least for me. Notice the `Position 1` and `Position 2` (at the end of code). The position 1 is placed just after the `animation` function, the other one is placed **just after** code-wise, since the function ends after position 1 and therefore goes to position 2.

Since `FuncAnimation` requires the `figure` to run the animation on, I am wondering why the `plt.show()` works on Position 1, but not on Position 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html) states about `FuncAnimation`

> It is critical to keep a reference to the instance object. The animation is advanced by a timer (typically from the host GUI framework) which the Animation object holds the only reference to. If you do not hold a reference to the Animation object, it (and hence the timers), will be garbage collected which will stop the animation.

If you put `plt.show()` outside of the `anim_random_points` function, the variable `ani`, which holds the reference to the animation, will be garbage collected and there will be no animation to be shown any more.

The solution for that case would be to return the animation from that function

```
def anim_random_points(fig, axis):
    # ...
    ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(...)
    return ani

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # ...
    ani = anim_random_points(...)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: I do not understand the second issue. It will probably be better off in a new question, which can be understood standalone (as it even doesn't seem to be related to matplotlib at all).

Comment: I will ask a different question when the timer between questions will be off. Thanks a lot for your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should really ask two separate questions.

I can answer the first one. The difference between the two positions is due to the fact that `ani` is a local variable to your function `anim_random_points()`. It is automatically deleted when the execution reaches the end of the function. Therefore `plt.show()` in position 2 has nothing to display.

If you want to use `plt.show()` in position 2, you need to return the ani object from your function, and keep a reference to it in the main part of your code.

```
def anim_random_points(fig, axis):
    (...)
    ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(...)
    return ani


if __name__ == '__main__':
    (...)
    ani = anim_random_points(fig, axis)

    #   Position 2 for plt.show()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: You're right, I should have asked only one question. Thanks for your input. I will however validate ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer as he provided documentation as bit more specific to the local variable thing. But you won my upvote ! Thanks for answering. :)