# Event OnClick Matplotlib display points and save

Tags: python, matplotlib, onclick, qt-designer

Problem solve at that post in matplotlib documentation: https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/event_handling.html

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, you may have a look at this

[Matplotlib Plot Points Over Time Where Old Points Fade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48152754/matplotlib-plot-points-over-time-where-old-points-fade)

For the second one, try something like this

```
#list to store the points
points = []

#click event
def onclick(event):
    global points
    print('button=%d, x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f' %
          (event.button, event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata))
    #store the points in a list
    points.append([event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata])
    plt.plot(event.xdata, event.ydata, ',')
```

With every click, the set of points is added to the points list. Vice versa, if you want to access e.g. the coordinates, stored with the third click, simply type

```
print(f"x={points[2][0]}, y={points[2][1]}, xData={points[2][2]}, yData={points[2][3]}")
```