# Can scatter plot dots be animated to change color and brightness while fading out over time?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, scatter-plot, brightness

I would like to animate dots in a scatter plot with changing colors and brightness.

Is there a simple way to add dots to a scatter plot with `matplotlib`  and brighten the old ones with every new dot?
The goal would be that one can see in an animation only the most current dots in dark colors; the old one should vanish step by step?

Comment: Hi, B. Flurl!  Right now, this question isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow, since it is a very open-ended question on data visualization.  Do you have a specific programming language you're using to accomplish this task?  Have you attempted to solve the problem on your own and gotten stuck?  Have you searched for relevant documentation/similar questions which might solve your problem?  This site is best for getting specific answers to definite problems where you show what you've already tried and include any relevant code in your question.

Comment: Hi,

oh, sorry, it's Python...
I'm trying to manage it with mathplotlib.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like someone has already solved your issue (with an animated demonstration included!) over on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48152754/matplotlib-plot-points-over-time-where-old-points-fade?noredirect=1&lq=1  If this solution works for you, you might want to close your question as a duplicate of that one, to show future visitors that they can find the answer there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib Plot Points Over Time Where Old Points Fade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48152754/matplotlib-plot-points-over-time-where-old-points-fade)